# Interior of sum of sets equals sum of interior of summands

Tags: general-topology, geometry, convex-analysis

I'd like to have the answer to the following question. If $X_1,X_2\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ are convex and compact sets of dimension $n$, does the following hold:

$$\mathrm{\mathop{int}}(X_1+X_2)\subseteq\mathrm{\mathop{int}}(X_1)+\mathrm{\mathop{int}}(X_2)$$

? I expect the equation above to be true, but I don't have a proof yet. The case I'm struggling with is, when we suppose a $y\in\mathrm{\mathop{int}}( X_1+X_2)$ has a decomposition $y=x_1+x_2$, where $x_i\in\mathrm{\mathop{bd}} (X_i)$. I checked the following link:

[Relative interior of the sum of two convex sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556347/relative-interior-of-the-sum-of-two-convex-sets)

It suggests, to use a rpresentation $y=\lambda y_1+(1-\lambda)y_2$, where $y_i\in X_1+X_2$ and $\lambda\in(0,1)$. Then we may write $y_i=x_1^{(i)}+x_2^{(i)}$, where $x_j^{(i)}\in X_j$, and we find

$$y= \left(\lambda x_1^{(1)}+(1-\lambda)x_1^{(2)}\right)+\left(\lambda x_2^{(1)}+(1-\lambda)x_2^{(2)}\right).$$

He proceeds to argue, that $\lambda x_j^{(1)}+(1-\lambda)x_j^{(2)}\in\mathrm{\mathop{int}}(X_j)$, but how do we know, that the line $\left[x_j^{(1)},x_j^{(2)}\right]$ is not contained in the boundary?

Answer (score 0):

NO it does not hold in $\Bbb R ^2$  take $X_1=0$ and $X_2 = \Bbb B$ closed Unit ball. then $\rm RHS  = \emptyset$

It does hold if   $\rm int ~ X_i  \neq \emptyset , ~~ i=1,2$ .

Comment: The set $X_1=\{0\}$ is not of dimension $2$.

Comment: On the other hand, I guess that $\operatorname{int} X_i  \ne \varnothing$ holds provided $X_i$ (which is convex and compact) has dimension $n$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky  yes you are right, even compactness is redundant ..

But in OP argument, there is no use of assumption being full dimension